# How to change customize theme, background color in Visualforce that using Design system?

Tags: visualforce, lightning-design-system, design-tokens

I have completed the tutorial applying [Design System in Visualforce](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/lightning_design_system/units/lightning-design-system2). I read about design tokens but I still don't understand how we can change the theme in Visualforce.

I am not able to find an example how to change and customize the theme in VF, for example if I want to change design system button to orange.

I read design token in the site , it has Sass format and lightning format.
The example given is:

```
t(colorBackgroundPathIncompleteHover)
```

How I can use this in Visualforce?

Comment: I have been wondering the same thing. I have seen no examples of actually using design tokens in visual force and SLDS.

Answer (score 3):

After reading several posts and checking [Using Design Tokens with the Lightning Design System](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBEc3dJJV8), it seems that you have to embed a lightning component that uses design tokens. 
It doesn't look like you can use design tokens directly within a Visualforce page, if you are developing web-based applications, you can use te design tokens as variables through CSS preprocessors Sass, Less, and Stylus.

[image]

That being said, if you are developing a vf page using an an IDE, you can download the package via [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@salesforce-ux/design-system) or the [web page](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/downloads/) and you will have to use a compiler prior to deploying your page and static resources to Salesforce